# Posting to Nodejs api server using Chrome postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

I am trying to test my Nodejs api server using Chrome postman tool by posting raw JSON data, yet I can't figure out how to post an array or array of objects. Below is my mongodb schema and the json I tried sending from Chrome postman to test the saving function. Can someone please tell me what I am missing / doing wrong here, thanks.

```
var memberSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', memberSchema);

var commentPics = new Schema({
    url: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        max: 1000
    }
});

var comment = new Schema({
    subject: String,
    body: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        max: 2000
    },
    dateAdded: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    pics:[commentPics],
    members:[type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Member']   
});


Data posted by Chrome - Postman

{"subject":"New comment", "body":"this is a test", "pics.url":"http://www.google.com", "members":"[123456, 567890]"}
```

Comment: Your "array" is a string, not a real array. The last part needs to be `"members":[123456, 567890]"}`. Modify that and try re-POSTing.

Comment: @mscdex Tried {"subject":"test", "body":"this is a test", "members":[123456, 5892031]} and {"subject":"test", "body":"this is a test", "members":"[123456, 5892031]"} both returned  "Message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"123456,5892031\" at path \"members\""

Comment: You might try quoting each individual member ObjectId then: `"members":["123456", "567890"]}`

Comment: @mscdex Just tried it and got a new error  "Message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"123456,5892031\" at path \"members\"", "name": "CastError", "type": "ObjectId", "value": ["123456","5892031"],"path":"members"